# Intercept client disconnect with spring?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest

I have a spring based web service (JAX-RS), and I want to intercept client disconnection in case a long operation is running.
For example, when a client preform an HTTP call, that creates a load of work on the server, but then disconnects for some reason (process terminated), I would like to intercept that disconnection and cancel the work on the server, since the client will never get the result he was waiting for.

Is that possible with spring?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you start the processing asynchronously and create a method like `getStatus()` which is available for client to check the status periodically. That should do it

Comment: I do. But I'm also providing the client with a blocking approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but that has nothing to do with Spring.

Even if you had direct access to the socket used for HTTP transport, you could not detect that the other peer has closed the socket without trying to read from or write to it. That is not possible without conflicting with any HTTP protocol handlers, obviously also trying to use the socket.

Comment: I think he can use some workaround with javascript based on window.onbeforeunload event and triger the desired stop with ajax.

Comment: I disagree. It is possible to know if a TCP socket has been gracefully closed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination ("When an endpoint wishes to stop its half of the connection, it transmits a FIN packet, which the other end acknowledges with an ACK.")